# Determine and do stuff in foreach loop except the last iteration

Tags: php, foreach

I am looping a foreach and i need to make some logic like this:
if the iteration is not the last. Gather up the prices. when the iteration is the last. subtract from the total with the gathered up prices. except the last iteration price. I got the following code not. but it's not working.

```
    $i = 0;
    $credit = '';
    $count = count($reslist);

    foreach ($reslist as $single_reservation) {
            //All of the transactions to be settled by course
            //$credit             = $this->Reservations_model->find_res_price($single_reservation['value']) * $this->input->post('currency_value');

            if ($i > $count && $single_reservation != end($reslist)) {
                $gather_sum_in_czk += $this->Reservations_model->find_res_price($single_reservation['value']) * $this->input->post('currency_value');
                $credit             = $this->Reservations_model->find_res_price($single_reservation['value']) * $this->input->post('currency_value');
            }
            //Last iteration need to subtract gathered up sum with total.
            else {
                $credit = $suminczk - $gather_sum_in_czk;
            }
    $i++;
    }
```

EDIT: TRYING TO GATHER UP PRICES FOR ALL INTERACTIONS EXECPT LAST:

```
          if ($i != $count - 1 || $i !== $count - 1) {
                $gather_sum_in_czk += $this->Reservations_model->find_res_price($single_reservation['value']) * $this->input->post('currency_value');
                $credit             = $this->Reservations_model->find_res_price($single_reservation['value']) * $this->input->post('currency_value');
            }

            else {
                $credit = $suminczk - $gather_sum_in_czk;
            }
```

Comment: You have a counter `$i` and a total count in `$count`, so surely an `if ($i == $counter) { }` will catch the last one?

Comment: On `$i > $count` in the first loop, $i is 0, hence, how can it greater than $count?

Comment: See my edit. i need to first gather up all execpt last. then use the last

Comment: Share array structure for `$reslist`;

Comment: If you know how many times the loop is going to run, then save the no as a variable and check it's value in each corresponding iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SPL CachingIterator](http://docs.php.net/CachingIterator) is always one element behind its inner [iterator](http://docs.php.net/class.iterator.php). It can therefore report whether it will produce a next element via [->hasNext()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/cachingiterator.hasnext.php).
For the example I'm choosing a [generator](http://docs.php.net/generators) to demonstrate that this approach doesn't rely on any additional data like e.g. count($array).

```
<?php
// see http://docs.php.net/CachingIterator
//$cacheit = new CachingIterator( new ArrayIterator( range(1,10) ) );
$cacheit = new CachingIterator( gen_data() );

$sum = 0;                  
foreach($cacheit as $v) {
    if($cacheit->hasNext()) {
        $sum+= $v;
    }
    else {
        // ...and another operation for the last iteration
        $sum-=$v;
    }
}

echo $sum; // 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9-10 = 35


// see http://docs.php.net/generators
function gen_data() {
    foreach( range(1,10) as $v ) {
        yield $v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`foreach`-ing an array in PHP returns both the key (integer index if pure array) and value. To be able to use the value, use the following construct:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
...
}
```

then you can check whether `$key >= count($array) - 1` (remember in a 0-based array, the last element is `count($array) - 1`.

Your original code almost works, just wrong in the `if` condition. Use `$i >= $count - 1` instead of `$i > $count`.

Comment: Using the keys only works if you use numeric indexed values for the array keys. As @Prague2 hasn't shown how the array is created or populated, that's a bit of an assumption. Using the `$i` counter is more reliable.

Comment: My array storing keys and values only not numeric

Comment: Indeed that's an assumption for the keys. However, the last paragraph applies.